# Debian Wireless Problems using Ndiswrapper on Motherboard: Asus Rampage V Extreme

Tags: linux, networking, wireless-networking, drivers, debian

I have been trying to get my wireless working with Debian Linux for the past month now with no avail. I am using an Asus Rampage V Extreme with a wireless card: Broadcom Broadcom Limited BCM4360 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter (rev 03).

I have obtained multiple versions of the windows driver and tried to install them using Ndiswrapper, none of which have worked. I have followed all the online tutorials.

lspci gives me:

```
05:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Limited BCM4360 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter (rev 03)
```

ndiswrapper -l gives me:

```
bcmwl64 : driver installed
device (14E4:43A0) present (alternate driver: bcma)
```

ip addr gives me:

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1
link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eno1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
link/ether f0:79:59:62:b3:e0 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
inet 192.168.0.111/24 brd 192.168.0.255 scope global dynamic eno1
   valid_lft 83876sec preferred_lft 83876sec
inet6 fe80::2561:950f:c23c:4fd7/64 scope link 
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

I am about 3 months into learning Linux so I am not an expert but by no means am I a novice.

If you need more info, leave a comment and I will add it ASAP.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: ndiswrapper is a hack. If at all possible, don’t use it. [There are native drivers available.](https://wiki.debian.org/wl)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the drivers from [here](http://wiki.debian.org/wl) and follow the instructions.

1:

```
apt-get install linux-image-$(uname -r|sed 's,[^-]*-[^-]*-,,') linux-headers-$(uname -r|sed 's,[^-]*-[^-]*-,,') broadcom-sta-dkms
```

2:

```
modprobe -r b44 b43 b43legacy ssb brcmsmac bcma
```

3:

```
modprobe wl
```